There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'y' of 'Vector2.Vector2(float, float)'
I don't know what I did wrong, please help.
When I remove Unity.Engine. (put behind Vector2) I get two errors:
'Vector2' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Vector2' and 'System.Numerics.Vector2'
'Vector2' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Vector2' and 'System.Numerics.Vector2'
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    float horizontal;

    [SerializeField] float Speed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] float JumpForce = 20f;


    [SerializeField] Rigidbody2D rb;

    [SerializeField] Transform groundcheck;
    [SerializeField] Transform groundcheck2;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask GroundLayer;

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded())
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(JumpForce * rb.velocity.x); //problem here
        }
    }

     void FixedUpdate()
     {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");        
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * Speed, rb.velocity.y); //and here
     }


    private bool isGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundcheck.position, 0.2f, GroundLayer); 
    }
}


The error in your question title is totally different than the ones listed in your post body. Which one of them are you actually getting?

This is a poorly written question. If you hit one error message, then changed your code and got a different error message then all that should be explained in the question in detail. The question should contain ALL the relevant information and the title should then be a summary of that, not an error message.

Sorry if my question was poorly writen, It's my first time on this website and i'm still learning english. Thanks for the feedback.

The message tells you there are two types with name Vector2: System.Numerics.Vector2 and UnityEngine.Vector2. Depending on which you want, either remove the other using statement, or specify the type using the full name:
rb.velocity = new UnityEngine.Vector2(JumpForce * rb.velocity.x);

